# Don't have access to head - Need to Add Meta OG Tags by either JQuery/PHP

Tags: php, html, facebook, meta

I know this method isn't ideal, but I have no alternative.  I can't access the head, and I need to add OG tags to a page.  I tried simply embedding them into the page on the off-chance that it might work, but I only received a warning about the error in the Facebook Debugger.

I tried to add them to the head by javascript, but that all works on the surface since that appears after the page has loaded....I assume PHP would be the only practical way to add in the og:title, og:image, and og:description I need.

Does anyone know if/how it is possible to add the meta tags to the head so that Facebook will detect them?  Again, I know this isn't the best way to go about it, but I only have access to the body content.  Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Well, using PHP output buffering they could be added “after” the HTML code of the page is assembled … but that is a complex and error-prone approach; you are better off fixing what causes this problem in the first place (and that is the inflexibility of your current system, that doesn’t allow you to generate output into the `head` element.)

Comment: I too do not have access to the head ... trying to find a way to enter a google metatag in the head.

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook bot does not call JavaScript, so the Open Graph Tags can´t be added with JavaScript. Your need to add them in your PHP code, but you can´t do that AFTER page load - that´s not how PHP works.

Also, use the debugger to check if the Open Graph Tags are correct: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/